# How to efficiently replace elements of char string with different integer elements?

Tags: c++, string, replace, integer

I am looking to replace the elements of character string with integer elements. I want to replace `A` with `1`, `B` with `2`, `C` with `3` and `D` with `4`.

How can I do it efficiently?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{
    std::string str = "ABCDDCBA";

    std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), 'A', '1'); // Replacing 
    std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), 'B', '2');  
    std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), 'C', '3'); 
    std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), 'D', '4');  
    // ...

    std::cout << str << std::endl; // displaying 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your data is so small and your program so simple and today's computers so fast and compilers so good that just about **any** solution will be efficient, without any chance to even measure a difference.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Have `2000000000` length

Comment: What do you mean? A string of length 18?

Comment: Or do mean 2^9? That's 512. It's still nothing. Did you actually measure the speed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method is quite efficient for replacing an arbitrary character with another arbitrary character.

However, currently you replace continuous latin alphabet with continuous integer digits, so you can take advantage of the fact that ASCII representations are also contiguous:

```
for(char& c : str)
     c += '1' - 'A';
```

Of course, this depends on the native character encoding to represent contiguous latin alphabet with contiguous values, such as ASCII does. It also depends on the digits being represented contiguously, but that is mandated by the standard.

Furhtermore, this method currently has no check for replaced character, and will change all encountered characters. This is not an issue with your input string, but if you intend to only replace some types of characters and leave others untouched, then you'll need to add a condition check.

Comment: @AwaitedOne this has O(n) complexity compared to your O(n * m), where n and m are the length of the string and the number different character mappings.

Comment: Great!! Will it work for any non continuous alphabets say `ADGI`

Comment: @AwaitedOne I don't know of ADGI, but in general, this requires that the alphabet characters that are to be replaced must be represented with consecutive values in the native encoding, as stated in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you mean do the replacement in one traversal? There are flashy C++ Standard Library ways of doing this, or you could even solve it with `std::regex`. But exploiting the overloaded `[]` operator on the `std::string` class will be hard to beat in terms of performance and is clear.

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i){
    switch (str[i]){
    case 'A':
        str[i] = '1';
        break;
    case 'B':
        /*etc*/
    }
}
```

If you are transforming more than a handful of characters (I took your question literally that you only wanted to map A, B, C, and D), then consider defining a `const char[]` array that describes the transformation; relying on the *values* of particular characters is not strictly portable C++.

Comment: Any algorithm will be O(length of string). Defining the transformation with a `const char[]` array will be difficult, if not impossible, to beat. It will also be completely portable.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try if input string only contains caps alphabet in ASCII format

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

std::string str = "ABCDDCBA";
for(int i=0;i<str.size();i++)
{
    str[i]=str[i]-'A'+'0';
}
std::cout << str << std::endl; // displaying 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice but not strictly portable. The alphas do not necessarily have to be consecutive. (They are in ASCII, but not in EBCDIC for example). If you mention that in the answer, I'll upvote.

Comment: @Bathsheba with the given input string, this happens to work with EBCDIC since A...I are contiguous. It's not explicitly stated whether characters outside of the range A...D may exist in the input string.

Comment: Touche. Yes this would work in EBCDIC for A, B, C, and D. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

A funny way to do that would be to use the ASCI value of each char:
by exemple: int('A') = 65, int('B') = 66 so you just have to do a boucle with
val = int(c) - 64; 
(Works only if you have maj char)

Answer (score 0):

One proposal in O(n)

```
void MyReplaceFunction(char& c)
{
    static const int delta='A'-'1';
    if(c>='A' && c<='Z')
    {
        c-=delta;
    }
}

std::for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), MyReplaceFunction);
```